# Add favicon to subpages

Tags: html, favicon

I have a favicon added to my website.

I know these things work for the entire page but I would like to know if this can be changed.

The website I'm running is static so every page is created manually.
I would like to have the subfolders to have their own favicon.

So I tried to add a favicon the the index.html that is in a subfolder. But it still uses the `root`'s favicon.

Can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="yourfolder/your_favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Yeah I did exactly that.

Comment: Browsers can be very persistant in caching favicons, try another browser or clear cache. Also `yourfolder` is relative to the subfolder you're already in.

Comment: I'm f-ing stupid. I used the wrong folder. My bad! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use different layouts for the pages OR you create a favicon variable like `<%= yield :favicon %>` and then in your pages add the `<%= content_for :favicon %>` and make that match your image.

I thought you are trying to make your favicon more variable. ;-) So did you solve it now?